# Condition for sequence to be differentiable at 0

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ such that

$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
 c_n & \text{if }x=\frac1n\text{ for some }n\in\mathbb N \\
0 & \text{elsewhere}  \\
\end{cases}$$
where
$c_n$ is a given sequence. Find the condition on the sequence $c_n$ such that $f'(0)$ exists.

Here is what I got, I'm actually not sure only about the last part, when I choose the condition for my $N$.

So now, be definition of derivative, $f'(0)$ defined when $$\lim_{x\to0}{f(x)-f(0)\over x-0}=\lim_{x\to0}{f(x)\over x}$$
Now, if $x={1\over n}$ then 
${f(x)\over x} =
\begin{cases}
nc_n  & \text{for n =1,2,3...} \\
0 & \text{elsewhere}  \\
\end{cases}  
$

We have $$f'(0)=\lim_{x\to0}{f(x)\over x}=\lim_{n\to\infty}{f(1/n)\over 1/n}=lim_{n\to\infty}{c_n\over 1/n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}{nc_n}.$$

Now, $f'(0)$ exists only when $\lim_{n\to\infty}{nc_n}=0$.
So this is our condition. Let $\epsilon>0$, need to find an $N>0$ such that $$|nc_n-0|<\epsilon \text{ for }n>N$$ $\rightarrow |c_n|<{\epsilon\over |n|}$

Let $N={\epsilon\over |n|}$ so that we have $$|nc_n|<|n|{\epsilon\over |n|}=\epsilon$$

So $\lim_{n\to\infty}nc_n=0$ hence, $f$ is differentiable at $0$. And we have it (?)

What do you think?

Comment: Read it under your nick,@user45593. You have accpet rate of 25%, which means you've only accepted as "the best answer" about one quarter of the questions you've asked, and this could mean you don't really like the answers you get here.

Comment: Oh, ok, thanks. And I do like the answer I get here. And sometimes, I answered question myself also, just like this one.

Comment: Do you think my answer is right though?

Comment: Yes, it looks fine.

Comment: You "wrote something wrong" at some point : when you write : when $x = 1/n$, $f(x) = \{ nc_n,$ if $x = 1/n$ for $n = 1,2, \dots$. It should be written $c_n$ instead of $nc_n$. And you could've stopped at "So this is our condition." The rest is irrelevant. But the argument is fine

Answer (score 1):

Most books define differentiable functions on an interval $ (a, b) $. But we can define the derivative of a function $ f: A \to \mathbb {R} $ at a point $ c \in A $  if is $ c $ is an accumulation point ( or cluster point ) of $ A $.

Then $f^\prime(c)$ is unic number  that have the propert:

$$
\forall \epsilon >0, \exists \delta=\delta(c,\epsilon)>0\quad \mbox{ such that } x\in A \mbox{ e }0<|c-x|<\delta \implies \left|\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}- f^\prime(c) \right|<\epsilon. $$